# Are PS+ Games Free Games Shareable With Other Accounts On the Same PS3?

Tags: ps3

When I get PS+, will other accounts on my PS3 be able to access the game as long as my account with PS+ has a subscription? Or are the games only accessible to my account, even if the other accounts are on the same console? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Every profile on the system can play any game as long as the account that holds the PS+ subscription is present and active, even if profiles are for other regions. For instance I have both a US and JPN profile on my system and play all the JPN titles from my US profile.

If you cancel the PS+ subscription then all of the Free titles become locked. Any game you purchased, even at a discounted rate is still accessible to all profiles.

Comment: To add on to this question... If you have a JP and US profile, and your PSN subscription runs out, and you renew it, can you leave off like nothing ever happened (say you stopped for a month, then renewed it)? Just curious because I've wanted to try some Japan games.

Comment: Yes. Once you resubscribe you regain access to the games but you will need to go through the process of re-downloading them in order for them to change from expired to active (as long as they haven't expired for other reasons such as no longer being available for download in your market).

Comment: By the way, if this answered your question, would you mind check-marking it as "accepted"? Thanks!